# wheel group in OpenSolaris

Tags: solaris, opensolaris, openindiana

What is the equivalent of 'wheel' group in OpenSolaris/OpenIndiana? I used to add a user in the wheel group and permit the group to execute commands via sudo without password asked. I want to do the same in OpenSolaris/Indiana.

I see 'staff' group having the same gid in OpenSolaris, as wheel in Linux for example (Fedora or CentOS).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no `wheel` group or equivalent under these OSes although nothing forbids to create one and configure sudo to allow passwordless root commands.

A more "Solaris style" alternative might be to grant these users the "Primary Administrator" profile and/or grant them the root role. Not sure you will avoid a password prompt though.